# How \show must print null control sequence?

Tags: tex-core

On p.46 of TeXbook it is said `\csname\endcsname` is the same as empty (aka null) control sequence.

But why they are printed differently by `\show`? Compare

```
\endlinechar=-1
\def\
{a}
\def\x{\
}
\show\x
```

versus

```
\endlinechar=-1
\def\
{a}
\def\x{\csname\endcsname}
\show\x
```

What are the rules here and which case deviates from them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The rule you quote means that these two `\show` are showing the same csname token

```
\expandafter\show\csname\endcsname

\endlinechar=-1

\show\

\bye
```

In your case you are not showing the token with empty name but two different definitions of `\x` in the first case the replacement text of `\x` is the single csname with empty name, which `\show` shows as `\csname\endcsname` but the second definition has replacement text the two tokens `\csname` and `\endcsname` these have not been executed so as usual `\show` shows a space after both the names `\csname \endcsname`